# How to Authenticate Google Drive API on Server (Ubuntu)?

Tags: java, ubuntu, google-drive-api, google-authentication

[image]

When I run this Application in my local it ask for same Verification For Once per machine and then Runs Completely Fine. When I Ran this Server And I get this Auth URL i am Not Able to Authenticate it With My browser because Callback URL Calls that Localhost:40131 server shown In Image and my Application is Running On 443.
How to Authenticate this ?

Comment: just like the Error Message say: open the url (it should be the developer console) and add your new localhost:40131 or localhost:443 to the API

Comment: You should edit the `redirect_uri` so that it matches the port your app is running on: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#step-2:-send-a-request-to-googles-oauth-2.0-server

Comment: If I put Redirect Uri to The Port I am running my application then it will say Address already in use

Comment: Hi! Could you please share a sample of your code/section of it where you authentificate with the Drive API? Also, do you have your credentials.json in the project folder?